# Pagination in C# - can I simplify my code?

Tags: c#, pagination

**Can I simplify my code?**

I have list of long. Im using some API, that accepts up to 25 records per method call.

I wrote simple pagination

```
List<long> items = new List<long>(); // this will contain 100+ records

int itemsCnt = items.Count();
int pagesCnt = (itemsCnt + (itemsCnt % 25)) / 25; // calculating total pages

int page = 0;

while (page < pagesCnt)
{
    List<long> itemsSinglePageList = items.GetRange(page, 25);

    ProcessPageOfRecords(itemsSinglePageList);
    page++;
}
```

Im wondering if I can simplify this a bit.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I feel stackoverflow is going wrong way. I wonder when websites like "questions_about_for_loops_in_cpp.stackexchange.com" or "questions_about_tables_in_html.stackexchange.com" start appearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int pagesCnt = (itemsCnt + (itemsCnt % 25)) / 25; // calculating total pages
```

This is not what you want. The modulus is the **remainder**, which means it's used for subtraction, not addition. The following two are correct, but I prefer the latter:

```
int pagesCnt = ((itemsCnt - (itemsCnt % 25)) / 25) + 1; 

int pagesCnt = Math.Ceiling ( (double)itemsCnt / 25 ) ; //Rounding up is basically what you want here.
```

However, for an indepth review, I sugggest posting this to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ as they are more suited to these types of answers.

**Edit** To explain why the modulus usage is wrong in your case:

Suppose there are 26 items. Let's use your formula:

```
(itemsCnt + (itemsCnt % 25)) / 25

(26 + (26 % 25)) / 25

(26 + (1)) / 25

(27 ) / 25

//Not casted as double, so it's an int division
1
```

Using my example:

```
Math.Ceiling ( (double)itemsCnt / 25 )

Math.Ceiling ( (double)26 / 25 )

Math.Ceiling ( 1.04 )

2
```

Comment: I messed up with that modulus... Thanks for catching that and for the tip with Math.Ceiling() method. This is what I wanted indeed.

Comment: No problem, it's easy to make a mistake in these types of calculations :) For some reason, modulus is an underused operation, as I see multiple occurences of wrong usages, or in the case of cyclical int values, simply opting for `if(myCounter == cyclusSize) myCounter = 0;` instead of `myCounter = ++myCounter % cyclusSize;`. I find it strange that people don't default to using modulus for cyclical operations, but maybe my math background causes me to work with it more frequently than other developers.

Comment: I agree that such calculations are error-prone. The best solution is to avoid them... Check my answer below regarding generating batches without making such calculations.

Comment: @st4hoo: This is not meant purely against you, and no offense is intended, but I find it horribly wrong that developers are now all accepting that "difficult things should not be used, ever!". True, it's rather easy to create obfuscated code when using operations that need few characters, because people try to fit too much on a single line. The issue there is that *people fit too much code on a single line*, not that *modulus is too difficult for anyone to even consider using it correctly*.

Comment: @Flatter: I didn't say that "difficult things should not be used, ever!". I said that you should avoid error-prone techniques. Such approach allows to reduce the risk of mistake. And the other point is: why to reinvent the wheel when you want just to use it?

Comment: @st4hoo I didn't intend to put words in your mouth. It's the best description I could find for a general way of thinking a lot of developers seem to adopt. Also, my answer wasn't directly concerned with OP's final plan with the code. For that, codereview.stackexchange.com is the site to go to, as I mentioned. I only spotted a direct contradiction in the intent of the code, and addressed it as such.

Answer (score 1):

```
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(1,100);
var items_per_page =25;
var pages = numbers.Count ()/items_per_page;

for (int i = 0; i < pages; i++)
{
    // Do something like
    var some_var = numbers.Skip(i*items_per_page).Take(items_per_page);
    // use that some_var in funky ways
}
```

That should do it ...

Comment: I thought of this, but this should be poor performing isn't it.

Comment: this should be good for reading and understanding, which for a 100 objects, trumps performance ... If you're worried about performance, you can add `ToArray`, and just use indexes ...

Answer (score 1):

Do you *need* to use PageSize & PageNo?

I've found changing to olny using Skip & Take, and then relying on Linq do do everything for me, far easier & less bug-prone:

```
var toShow = items.Skip(skip).Take(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/)'s batching method.

You can quickly create batches out of source collection like this:

```
var batches = Enumerable.Range(1,100000).Batch(25);
```

so your logic after some refactoring will be like this:

```
List<long> items = new List<long>(); // this will contain 100+ records

items.Batch(25).ForEach(batch => ProcessPageOfRecords(batch));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the most effective but done in one Linq.

```
int pageSize = 25;
var pages = list.Select((item, i) => new { Page = i/pageSize, Item = item })
    .GroupBy(g => g.Page)
    .Select(d => new { Page = d.Key, Items = d.Select(i => i.Item).ToList() })
    .ToList()
```