# How to create pagination with dots and pure html in webforms c#

Tags: c#, html, pagination, webforms

I'm trying to create pagination but I'm unsure of how else to proceed with the dots.
I currently have something like this:

```
Prev | 1 2 3 4 5 ... 46 47 48 49 50 | Next
```

Here's my code for that

```
  public string CreatePagingLinks(int currentPage, int matches, string baseURL, int rowsPerPage)
    {
        string pagingInfo= "";

        int rangeFrom = rowsPerPage * (currentPage - 1) + 1;
        int rangeTo = rangeFrom + rowsPerPage - 1;
        int maxpages = (matches / rowsPerPage) + 1;
        int pagesShown = 5;

        if (currentPage == 1)
        {
            pagingInfo += "Prev | ";
        }
        else
        {
            pagingInfo += "<a href=\"" + baseURL + "page=" + (currentPage - 1).ToString() + "\">Prev</a> | ";
        }

        if(currentPage > 3)
        {
            //pagingInfo += "<a href=\"" + baseURL + "page=" + (pagesShown + 1 ).ToString() + "\">...</a> "
            pagingInfo += "...";
        }

   for (int k = 1; k <= pagesShown+1; k++)
           {
               if(k == pagesShown + 1)
               {
                   pagingInfo += "<a href=\"" + baseURL + "page=" + (pagesShown + 1 ).ToString() + "\">...</a> ";
               }
               else
               {
                   pagingInfo += "&nbsp;<a href=\"" + baseURL + "page=" + k.ToString() + "\">" + k.ToString() + "</a>&nbsp;";
               }

           }
 
        for (int k = maxpages-(pagesShown-1); k <= maxpages; k++)
        {
            pagingInfo += "&nbsp;<a href=\"" + baseURL + "page=" + k.ToString() + "\">" + k.ToString() + "</a>&nbsp;";
        }


        if (currentPage == maxpages)
        {
            pagingInfo += " | Next";
        }
        else
        {
            pagingInfo += " | <a href=\"" + baseURL + "page=" +  (currentPage + 1).ToString() + "\">Next</a>";
        }


        return pagingInfo;
    }
```

Which is something along the lines of what I want to do but I'm thinking that once the user wants page 6, it should look like this instead:

```
page 1: 1 2 3... 48 49 50
page 2: 1 2 3 ... 48 49 50
page 3: 1... 3 4 5... 48 49 50
```

or something like that concept.

I guess what I'm struggling with is how to change the numbers when the number approaches the end of the shown numbers...

Comment: have you looked at the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23734073/pagination-in-c-sharp-can-i-simplify-my-code

Comment: That question doesn't pertain to my question.